# SSIS Population of Slowly Changing Dimension with outrigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, data-warehouse

Working on a data warehouse, a suitable analogy for the problem is that we have Healthcare Practitioners. Healthcare Practitioners have a number of professional attributes and work in an open number of teams and in an open number of clinical areas.

For example, you may have a nurse who works in children's services across a number of teams as a relief/contractor/bank staff person. Or you may have a newly qualified doctor who works general medicine who is doing time in a special area pending qualifying as a consultant of that special area.

So we have an open number of areas of work and an open number of teams, we can't have team 1, team 2 etc in our dimensions. The other attributes may change over time also, like base location (where they work out of), the main team and area they work in..

So, following Kimble I've gone for outriggers:

Table DimHealthProfessionals:

```
Key (primary key, identity)
Name
Main Team
Main Area of Work
Base Location
Other Attribute 1
Other Attribute 2
Start Date
End Date
```

Table OutriggerHealthProfessionalTeam:

```
HPKey (foreign key to DimHealthPRofessionals.Key)   
Team Name
Team Type
Other Team Attribute 1
Other Team Attribute 2
```

Table OutriggerHealthProfessionalAreaOfWork:

```
HPKey (as above)
Area of Work
Other AoW attribute 1
```

If any attribute of the HP changes, or the combination of teams or areas of work in which they work change, we need to create a new entry in the SCD and it's outrigger tables to encapsulate this.

And we're doing this in SSIS.

The source data is basically an HP table with the main attributes, a table of areas of work, a table of teams and a pair of mapping tables to map a current set of areas of work to an HP.

I have three data sources, one brings in the HCP information, one the areas of work of all HCPs and one the team memberships.

The problem is how to run over all three datasets to determine if an HP has changed an attribute, and if they have changed an attribute, how we update the DIM and two outriggers appropriately.

Can anyone point me at a best practice for this? OR suggest an alternative way of modelling this dimension?

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I may not understand everything here, but it seems to me that the relationship in this example should be reversed. Place `TeamKey` and the `WorkAreaKey` in the `dimHealthProfessionals` -- this should simplify things.

With this in place, you simply make sure to deliver outriggers before the `dimHealthProfessionals`.

Treat outriggers as dimensions in their own right. You may want to treat `dimHealthProfessionals` as a type 2 dimension, to properly capture the history.

**EDIT**

Considering that team to person is many-to-many, a fact is more appropriate.
A column in a dimension table is appropriate only if a person can belong to only one team at a time. Same with work areas.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is how to run over all three datasets to determine if an HP has changed an attribute, and if they have changed an attribute, how we update the DIM and two outriggers appropriately.
>
> Can anyone point me at a best practice for this? OR suggest an alternative way of modelling this dimension?

I'm not sure I understand your question fully. If you are unsure about change detection, then use Checksums in the package. Build up a temp table with the data as it is in the source, then compare each row to its counterpart (joined via the business keys) by computing the checksum for both rows and comparing those. If they differ, the data has changed.

If you are talking about cascading updates in a historized dimension hierarchy (and you can treat the outriggers like a hierarchy in this context) then the foreign key lookups will automatically lookup the newer entry in DimHealthProfessionals if you have a historization (i.e. have validFrom / validThrough timestamps in DimHealthProfessionals). Those different foreign keys result in a different checksum.